# GTK+ caret-color CSS property in Evince

Tags: css, c, gtk, gtk3, gnome-3

Using a dark theme, the caret in Evince (press F7 to get to caret mode) is a very light colour and therefore doesn't show up well against the usual white background of a document.

I'd like to fix this, and I was going to hack a theme to do it, but on digging, it seems evince is using a deprecated property: `cursor-color` (at [ev-view.c:4260](https://github.com/GNOME/evince/blob/master/libview/ev-view.c#L4262)):

```
gtk_style_context_get_style (context,
                 "cursor-color",
                 &style_color,
                 NULL);
```

The fallback is:

```
gtk_style_context_save (context);                                   
gtk_style_context_get_color (context, GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL, color);
gtk_style_context_restore (context);
```

The deprecation was done [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/9f247e112bc34011f45addf14e6d1ba5df1e05c7). So I want to try to update evince to use the CSS property, and then update my theme to set this for `EvView` objects to apply it to evince's main document view:

I set the following CSS in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` as a test:

```
* {
     caret-color: rgba(0,255,0,1.0);
}
```

This does work for gedit, for example - the caret in the main editor and the dialogs are all green.

I then tried to read this out, using similar logic to the used internally by GTK for the caret colour (c.f. [gtk/gtkstylecontext.c @ 9b86d6da2](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/9b86d6da2cb26893223e64be29d2d016d18af77a#diff-a6b77f852eb73480d3960cdfaf3c28aa))

```
gtk_style_context_get (context,
                gtk_style_context_get_state (context),
                "caret-color", color,
                NULL);
```

However, this doesn't work and my colour is transparent black, not opaque green as expected. However, the call to `gtk_style_context_get()` is actually setting the colour to transparent black, not just leaving it alone.

Using just `GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL` instead of `gtk_style_context_get_state (context)` as the fallback used to doesn't work either.

What is the correct way to read this property such that I can set it in my theme and have it picked up?

Comment: It's hard to tell without the surrounding context, but you may be missing a `&` in `"caret-color", &color`. You need to pass a `GdkRGBA **` that gets filled in by the `gtk_style_context_get` call.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the caret color, you should do something like:

```c
GdkRGBA *caret_color;

gtk_style_context_get (context,
                       gtk_style_context_get_state (context),
                       "caret-color",
                       &caret_color,
                       NULL);
```

Later in the code, in Evince you had:

```c
if (style_color) {
    color->red = style_color->red / 65535.0;
    color->green = style_color->green / 65535.0;
    color->blue = style_color->blue / 65535.0;
    color->alpha = 1;
```

Where the color values were converted from `GdkColor` to `GdkRGBA`. That conversion is not needed once you obtain "caret-color", and I guess that may have changed the color as you expected.